# grails/gorm: assigning a property constrained by 'unique'

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails 2.4.2, but suspect this has more to do with ORM(hibernate) in-general.

I'm trying to re-assign an ordinal property in a collection of objects. This re-assignment constitutes a "re-shuffling" of the objects.

Given:

```
class Bar {
    int i
    static belongsTo = [foo:Foo]
    static constraints = { i unique: 'foo' }
}

class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars:Bar]
    static mapping = { bars sort: 'i' }
}
```

and,

```
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec
import grails.validation.ValidationException

class FooServiceIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    public static final IntRange BAR_RANGE = 0..9
    Foo foo

    def setup() {
        foo = Foo.build()
        (BAR_RANGE).each {
            Bar bar = Bar.build(i: it, foo: foo)
            foo.addToBars(bar)
        }
        foo.save(flush:true).refresh()
    }

    void "reshuffling i-s doesn't work"() {
        when:
        List l = (BAR_RANGE).collect()
        use(Collections) {l.shuffle()}
        foo.bars.eachWithIndex{b,int index -> b.i=l[index]}
        foo.save()

        then:
        ValidationException ex = thrown()
        ex.message =~ 'must be unique'
    }
}
```

How do I get the above shuffling attempt to push-through (I.E. not fall-over the unique constraint)?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the ORM will update the `Bar` instances one by one you can only achieve this if you first delete all `Bar` instances of `Foo` by

```
foo.bars*.delete(flush: true)
```

and then execute the rest of your test code.

**Why is that?**

Hibernate will create a single Update statement for each `Bar` instance and will most likely fail on the first update. Here is an example. Imagine you already have a `Bar` instance with `i = 4`. Since `i` is declared unique the update will fail.

```
UPDATE bar SET i = 4 WHERE id = ?;
```

This is the reason why you need to delete the whole collection `bars` first, before you start to flush your changes to the database. Hope this helps to explain the problem.

Comment: Deleting a group of objects just so that I could re-add them? I don't feel very comfortable with this... is that a best-practice for such use-cases?

Comment: Please find my explanation above

Comment: Thanks. I understand why an update fails, technically. I'm more interested in your last comment: if you're considering the above method of managing order as worst-practice, how would you do it?

I started-off with having a List<Bar> bars, but fell-back on grails' default - reason for which I can't recall anymore. Would that be your suggestion? Would that allow reshuffling of items in the collection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that you should define your `i` as unique. You should use the composite key instead, to incorporate `foo.id` AND the `i`. Otherwise you would run into conflicts between different Foo instances.

BTW, if you define your `Foo.bars` as `List` the `ix` positional column is added by GORM automatically

Comment: thanks @injecteer. Having an explicit 'i' property allows non-consecutive ordinals (e.g. "1,3,4,5,..."), and isn't necessarily 0-based. In-general, the 'i' property is not only there for ordering, but also to assign an actual numeric to the object.

Not sure I get your meaning about running 'into conflicts'. haven't used composite keys before, but skimming the docs suggests it may be over-engineering something equally-solvable with 'unique'.

The adding of an 'ix' when using a List: I'm not familiar with that feature. Is that documented? Is that an actual domain property?

Comment: I mean, that if you would use the `i` for ordering only and if it were 0- or 1- or whatever-based AND unique at the same time, then it would lead to clashes, if you try to assign the same `i` value to different `Bar` instances.

Comment: the `*_idx` (sorry for misspelling in the original post) column is added to the table for collections of `List` type and are are exposed to the domain class as elements' indices within a `List`. The `Set`s do not need this. This is what the ref-doc states: `The way this works at the database level is Hibernate creates a books_idx column where it saves the index of the elements in the collection to retain this order at the database level.`